# Unable to delete using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, spring-mvc

I have a simple delete method, it gets the id from a table that lists all from the db:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/personagem/excluir.htm")
public ModelAndView doExcluir(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
    logger.info("Recebendo parametro: {Id => " + id + "}");
    try {
        Personagem p = getPersonagemService().buscarPorId(id);
        logger.info("Excluindo personagem: {Id => " + p.getId() + ", Nome => " + p.getNome() + ", Classe => " + p.getClasse() + "}");
        getPersonagemService().excluir(p);
        return new ModelAndView("excluir");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new ModelAndView("erro", "mensagem", "Ocorreu um erro: " + ex);
    }
}
```

And heres the delete method from my dao:

```
public void excluir(Object obj) {
    getSession().beginTransaction();
    getSession().delete(obj);
    getSession().flush();
    getSession().close();
}
```

I click the delete button, that call for the doExcluir() method, that should delete the data. It comes back to the list page, as it should, but it just wont remove the data from the table. Did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not committing the transaction:

```
public void excluir(Object obj) {
    getSession().beginTransaction();
    getSession().delete(obj);
    getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    getSession().close();
}
```

As a side note, why don't you use Spring and its integrated transaction management to remove all this boilerplate code?

Comment: Thank you xD i dunno how to do that with spring, the way i did is the only way i know =/ Note: i did what u told and now i get this: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the [Spring's pet-clinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) example as a reference. I included relevant parts for your case:

```
public class HibernateClinic implements Clinic {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateClinic(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void deletePet(int id) throws DataAccessException {
        Pet pet = loadPet(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(pet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed my getSession() method was getting a new session everytime i called it, so on commit, it was committing a different session (i think). I just added: Session session = getSession();, used session instead of getSession() and it worked just fine xD

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Transactional` to your controller method.

Of course you need to configure Spring to recognize this.
But then you can skip a lot of the session an transaction handling code.